How can I handle user provisioning with Azure when a user is in multiple groups?
I have a working Azure user provisioning flow. The issue I am facing is if a user is in multiple groups I don't know how to set a priority system. Is there a way I can setup a priority system on Azure so that it knows which group is the correct group that the user should get their profile from?

Should this rather be handled by an apex class for JIT provisioning?

I have found a way to handle it, just in case someone stumbles across this question :)
Create a custom field on user that can take multiple values. Then on the user provisioning mapping on azure, assign all roles to that field. On Salesforce create a trigger that can then look at that field then call your custom profile precedence to determine which profile to assign.
You just need to add logic to the trigger, so it is not called unnecessarily.
Not an exact answer, but the logic should work :)
Here is an example of the trigger:
public with sharing class UserTriggerHandler {

    /**
     * createValidAzureUserList: Filters out the User records that are Azure user requests and processes them.
     * It extracts Azure Active Directory roles and sets them in a string format.
     * @param newUserList A list of User records to be processed.
     * @return A list of User records representing Azure user requests with processed Azure Active Directory roles.
     */
    private List<User> createValidAzureUserList(List<User> newUserList) {
        List<User> azureRequestUsers = new List<User>();
        for(User u: newUserList) {
            if (AzureRoleHandler.isAzureUserRequest(u)) {
                azureRequestUsers.add(u);
            }
        }
        for(User u: azureRequestUsers) {
            List<String> profiles = AzureRoleHandler.extractProfiles(u.AzureActiveDirectoryRoles__c);
            u.AzureActiveDirectoryRoles__c = profiles.toString();
        }
        return azureRequestUsers;
    }

    /**
     * beforeInsert: Trigger method called before User records are inserted.
     * It processes Azure user requests within the provided list of User records.
     * @param newUserList A list of User records to be processed before insertion.
     */
    public void beforeInsert(List<User> newUserList) {
        List<User> validUsers = createValidAzureUserList(newUserList);
    }

    /**
     * beforeUpdate: Trigger method called before User records are updated.
     * It processes Azure user requests within the provided list of User records.
     * @param newUserList A list of User records to be processed before update.
     */
    public void beforeUpdate(List<User> newUserList) {
        List<User> validUsers = createValidAzureUserList(newUserList);
    }

}

Here is the AzureRoleHandler:
note: The payload from Azure is a large xml string, so some logic to find the actual profile names is required.
public class AzureRoleHandler {

    /**
     * isAzureUserRequest: Determines if a user is an Azure user request based on the presence of Azure Active Directory roles.
     * @param newUser The User record to check.
     * @return Boolean indicating whether the user is an Azure user request.
     */
    public static Boolean isAzureUserRequest(User newUser) {
        return !String.isEmpty(newUser.AzureActiveDirectoryRoles__c);
    }

    /**
     * extractProfiles: Extracts profile names from a string representing Azure Active Directory roles.
     * @param input The string representing Azure Active Directory roles.
     * @return A list of profile names extracted from the input string.
     */
    public static List<String> extractProfiles(String input) {
        List<String> substrings = new List<String>();
        Integer startIndex = 0;
        while (true) {
            Integer openTagIndex = input.indexOf('<Value>', startIndex);
            if (openTagIndex == -1) {
                break;
            }
            Integer closeTagIndex = input.indexOf('</Value>', openTagIndex);
            if (closeTagIndex == -1) {
                break;
            }
            substrings.add(input.substring(openTagIndex + 7, closeTagIndex));
            startIndex = closeTagIndex + 8;
        }
        return filterValidProfiles(substrings);
    }
    
    /**
     * getValidProfileNames: Retrieves valid profile names from the Salesforce Profile object.
     * @return A set of valid profile names.
     */
    private static Set<String> getValidProfileNames() {
        Set<String> validProfileNames = new Set<String>();
        for (Profile userProfile : [SELECT Name FROM Profile]) {
            validProfileNames.add(userProfile.Name);
        }
        return validProfileNames;
    }
    
    /**
     * filterValidProfiles: Filters out invalid profile names from the provided list.
     * @param profileNames The list of profile names to be filtered.
     * @return A list of valid profile names.
     */
    private static List<String> filterValidProfiles(List<String> profileNames) {
        Set<String> validProfiles = getValidProfileNames();
        List<String> filteredProfiles = new List<String>();
        for (String profileName : profileNames) {
            if (validProfiles.contains(profileName)) {
                filteredProfiles.add(profileName);
            }
        }
        return filteredProfiles;
    }
}


If you can post an example trigger that'd be great. Don't forget to accept your own answer when you can (48 hours IIRC)

Not a problem :)

I know this question is old, but if you look into JIT (Just In Time) on Salesforce you can map attributes returned in the SAML response to fields on any object in Salesforce. In my use case I needed to add a permission set group, profile and role to the user based on the groups they are members of in Azure.

Also the Identity and Access Management Architect trail was very useful in learning more about this :)
